Inclusion of set $A$ in set $B$ or vice versa, where A and B are defined as follows:
Question
Consider the sets defined by the real solutions of the inequalities
$$
A=\left\{(x, y): x^2+y^4 \leq 1\right\} \quad B=\left\{(x, y): x^4+y^6 \leq 1\right\} .
$$
Then
(A) $B \subseteq A$
(B) $A \subseteq B$
(C) Each of the sets $A-B, B-A$ and $A \cap B$ is non-empty
(D) none of the above.
My attempt
It is clear that $|x|, |y| \leq 1$. Thus $x^{2} \geq x^{4}$ and $y^{4} \geq y^{6}$. Thus $1 \geq x^{2}+y^{4} \geq x^{4}+y^{6}$. Thus, $A \subseteq B$.
But how to conclude if the above inclusion is strict or not?

The inclusion is strict. Take $x = \pm 0.5$ and $y = \pm 0.95$.

You can give a counterexample: such pair $(x,y)$ that $x^2+y^4\gt1$, $x^4+y^6\le1.$ It’s clear that it’s better to search for such pair along the line $x=y$. So we get $$x^2+x^4\gt1$$ $$x^4+x^6\le1.$$
From the first (quadratic w.r.t $x^2$) inequality we get that we can take $x^2\gt \frac{\sqrt5-1}2$, for example $x^2=0.7$. Then $$x^4+x^6=0.7^2+0.7^3=0.49+0.343=0.833.$$
This is indeed not greater than $1$. So $(\sqrt{0.7},\sqrt{0.7})$ is in B, but not in A.
